# Using jinja if clause in ansible templated yaml (through template lookup )

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I've using ansible k8s module with a dynamic definition where I call it with

```yaml
- name: install some tool
  k8s:
    state: present
    definition: "{{ lookup('template', '{{item}}') }}"
    context: "{{ cluster_name}}"
  loop:
    - "tool_template.yaml"
```

And in the template I want to have a conditional block using a variable from the ansible role  (`is_major` in this case)

```yaml
metadata:
      labels:
        app: tool_name

      {% if is_major | bool %}
      annotations:
        ad.datadoghq.com/container.check_names: '["openmetrics"]'
        ad.datadoghq.com/container.init_configs: '[{}]'
        ad.datadoghq.com/container.instances: |
          [{
          "prometheus_url": "http://pathto:port/,
          "namespace": "myapp",
          "metrics": ["somemetric*"]
          }]
      {% endif %}
```

Unfortunately this blows up with an ansible exception and can't find a clue in the docs on how to do that (with recent docs at least) might be the fact I'm templating a yaml perhaps. so searching for a solution/workaround

ansible version 2.9

## EDIT: full error (with vvv)

```
The full traceback is:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588716858.967364-29993-207569799864998/AnsiballZ_k8s.py", line 102, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
    File "/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588716858.967364-29993-207569799864998/AnsiballZ_k8s.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
    File "/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588716858.967364-29993-207569799864998/AnsiballZ_k8s.py", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.clustering.k8s.k8s', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
    File "/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
    File "/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
    File "/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_d7uua9ug/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/modules/clustering/k8s/k8s.py", line 279, in <module>
    File "/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_d7uua9ug/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/modules/clustering/k8s/k8s.py", line 275, in main
    File "/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_d7uua9ug/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/k8s/raw.py", line 145, in __init__
    File "/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_d7uua9ug/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/k8s/raw.py", line 145, in <listcomp>
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 130, in load_all
    yield loader.get_data()
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_data
    return self.construct_document(self.get_node())
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 27, in get_node
    return self.compose_document()
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 223, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
    File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 579, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
    yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
    in "<unicode string>", line 18, column 24:
    annotations:
    ^
    failed: [localhost] (item=aks/monitor/datadog/datadog-agent-daemonset.yaml) => {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "changed": false,
        "item": "aks/monitor/datadog/datadog-agent-daemonset.yaml",
        "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588716858.967364-29993-207569799864998/AnsiballZ_k8s.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588716858.967364-29993-207569799864998/AnsiballZ_k8s.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588716858.967364-29993-207569799864998/AnsiballZ_k8s.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.clustering.k8s.k8s', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\n  File \"/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_d7uua9ug/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/modules/clustering/k8s/k8s.py\", line 279, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_d7uua9ug/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/modules/clustering/k8s/k8s.py\", line 275, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_d7uua9ug/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/k8s/raw.py\", line 145, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_d7uua9ug/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/k8s/raw.py\", line 145, in <listcomp>\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py\", line 130, in load_all\n    yield loader.get_data()\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py\", line 37, in get_data\n    return self.construct_document(self.get_node())\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 27, in get_node\n    return self.compose_document()\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 55, in compose_document\n    node = self.compose_node(None, None)\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 84, in compose_node\n    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 133, in compose_mapping_node\n    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 84, in compose_node\n    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 133, in compose_mapping_node\n    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 84, in compose_node\n    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 133, in compose_mapping_node\n    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 84, in compose_node\n    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py\", line 127, in compose_mapping_node\n    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/parser.py\", line 98, in check_event\n    self.current_event = self.state()\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/parser.py\", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key\n    if self.check_token(KeyToken):\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py\", line 116, in check_token\n    self.fetch_more_tokens()\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py\", line 223, in fetch_more_tokens\n    return self.fetch_value()\n  File \"/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py\", line 579, in fetch_value\n    self.get_mark())\nyaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here\n  in \"<unicode string>\", line 18, column 24:\n                annotations:\n                           ^\n",
        "module_stdout": "",
        "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
        "rc": 1
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the error message in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should remove the indentation in the template conditions, the spaces before the conditions are added to the spaces of the next line, because the new-line after the condition tag is being removed, which causes the `anotations` mapping to be double indented which is not expected.

Your current template results is:

```
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tool_name

      annotations:
    ad.datadoghq.com/container.check_names: '["openmetrics"]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/container.init_configs: '[{}]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/container.instances: |
      [{
      "prometheus_url": "http://pathto:port/,
      "namespace": "myapp",
      "metrics": ["somemetric*"]
      }]
```

This is how the template should look like:

```
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tool_name

{% if is_major | bool %}
  annotations:
    ad.datadoghq.com/container.check_names: '["openmetrics"]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/container.init_configs: '[{}]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/container.instances: |
      [{
      "prometheus_url": "http://pathto:port/,
      "namespace": "myapp",
      "metrics": ["somemetric*"]
      }]
{% endif %}
```

It is good it failed, because if the mapping before would reach the same indentation level it would simply input bad values into the deployment, or just wrong ones it the best case.

Read more about white-spaces in Jinja2: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#whitespace-control.

You can also control more the behavior by playing with `trim_blocks` and `lstrip_blocks` flags.

Answer (score 0):

You can not put {{ }} inside {{ }} so try remove extra block:

```
- name: install some tool
  k8s:
    state: present
    definition: "{{ lookup('template', item) }}"
    context: "{{ cluster_name}}"
  with_items:
    - "tool_template.yaml"
```

Comment: Nope, I can. because of the extra ` there. and I do it in other places, I've got a yaml/template issue, if it was that I would get the to the specific file